# Почему тут синтаксическая ошибка? (Python)

Tags: python

```py
Print=('Введите первое число')

num1=input()

Print=('Введите второе число')

num2=input()

Print=('Сумма чисел =' , num1+num2)

Print=('Разность чисел =' , num1-num2) # Синтаксическая ошибка
```

Comment: Приведите больше вашего кода, здесь видно что вы создали кортеж в котором элемент 1го индекса равен num1-num2

Comment: Тут нет синтаксической ошибки, чисто синтаксически этот код абсолютно корректен.

Answer (score 5):

Вам уже разжевали в нескольких ответах здесь. Я вас погружу немного глубже в язык.

Итак, операторы сложения и вычитания - это методы типов данных, которые определены как стандартные или как их называют "магические". Для сложения это `__add__()`, для вычитания - `__sub__()`.

#### Как это работает?

У нас есть такие переменные

```py
a = 5 # int тип данных
b = "this is something" #string тип данных
```

Каждая переменная содержит ссылку на значение с определенным типом данных. Так вот, тип данных и определяет можно ли применять те или иные методы к данному типу.

##### Пример с числом

Разберем переменную `a` и спросим, какие методы имеет этот тип данных

```py
>>> dir(a)
['__abs__',
 '__add__',
 '__and__',
 ....
 '__sub__',
 ....]
```

Как видим для данного типа данных определены оба метода и для сложения (`__add__()`) и для вычитания (`__sub__()`). Это значит, что мы можем прибавлять к переменной `a` и вычитать из нее. Одно из условий, методы должны быть определены у левого операнда.

```py
# никаких ошибок здесь не будет
a + 10
# эквивалент
a.__add__(10)

a - 10
# эквивалент
a.__sub__(10)
```

##### Пример со строкой

Теперь спросим методы для строки

```py
>>> dir(b)
['__add__',
 '__class__',        
 '__contains__',     
 '__delattr__',      
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',       
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__', 
 '__getitem__',      
 '__getnewargs__',   
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mod__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
....
]
```

Видим, что для строки определен метод `__add__()` и не определен метод `__sub__()`. Это значит, что к строке можно применять оператор сложения, но нельзя применять оператор вычитания.

```py
# нет ошибки
b + "new"
# эквивалент
b.__add__("new")

# а вот так уже нельзя
b - "new"
b.__sub__("new")
```

Answer (score 3):

исправил ваш код

```
num1 = int(input('первое '))
num2 = int(input('второе '))

print(f'разность {num1-num2} сумма {num1+num2}')
```

Вариант для вашего уровня владения `Python`:

```
num1 = int(input('первое '))
num2 = int(input('второе '))

res_sum = num1 - num2
res_min = num1 + num2

print('сложение', res_sum)
print('разность', res_min)
```

Компактный вариант

```
a,b = map(int, input().split())
print(f'сумма {a + b} разность {a - b}')
```

**Cложение и вычитание в Python**
В языке программирования `Python` есть специальные операторы с помощью которых можно складывать и вычитать числа, это `-` (минус) и `+` (плюс), для начала мы создадим две переменные и присвоим им значения которые введёт пользователь с помощью функции `input()`, так как `input()` изначально принимает строку а не число, а сложить и вычесть нам нужно всё таки числа, преобразуем тип вводимых данных из строки в число, вот так: `int(input('ваш ввод '))` далее, если нам нужно сохранить результат вычислений, то занесём его в отдельные переменные, вот так:

```
num1 = int(input('первое '))
num2 = int(input('второе '))

res_sum = num1 + num2
res_min = num1 - num2

print('сумма', res_sum)
print('разность', res_min)
```

Если нам не нужно сохранять результат вычислений то просто проведём все нужные операции в `print()`

```
num1 = int(input('первое '))
num2 = int(input('второе '))

print('сумма', num1 + num2)
print('разность', num1 - num2)
```

Comment: Гляньте мой ответ, я немного расширил понимание арифметических операторов. Думаю, вам будет интересно

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Введите первое число : ")

num1 = int(input()) 

print("Введите второе число: ")

num2 = int(input())

print("Сумма чисел = ", num1 + num2)

print("Разность чисел = ", num1 - num2)
```

здесь нужно представить переменные num1 и num2 в виде целочисленного числа int либо вещественного числа float. В вашем случае Вы просите ввести не  цифру, а строку  (по умолчанию str), так это воспринимает Python.

Answer (score 2):

Итак, у нас такая ошибка потому, что `input()` возвращает строку, а нам нужны числа, потому что мы работаем с числами. Для преобразования в число используем функцию `int()` после `input()`.
Строчка `Print=('Сумма чисел =' , num1+num2)` сработала без ошибки, потому что мы сложили эти две строчки.

Кроме того, вы создаете кортеж вместо вывода на экран. Функция `print()` используется вот так: `print("Текст")`

Итого:

```
print('Введите первое число')

num1 = int(input())

print('Введите второе число')

num2 = int(input())

print('Сумма чисел =' , num1+num2)

print('Разность чисел =' , num1-num2)
```

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно пометить функции как код.

Answer (score 2):

При вводе чисел в Python, функцию input нужно обернуть её в функцию int, вот пример с кодом:

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
```

Это что насчёт ввода.

Так же функции Print не нужно равно.

```
print('Введите первое число')
```

Ещё одно примечание: в input можно вводить текст:

```
input('Введите первое число: ')
```

Вот правильное решение:

```
num1 = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
num2 = int(input('Введите второе число: '))

print('Сумма num1 и num2:', num1+num2)
```

Удачи в дальнейшем изучении программирования.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй задать числам формат int() как писали выше - если ты не задаешь этот формат, система воспринимает то, что ты вводишь как строку а не число. Попробуй привыкнуть писать int(input()), через какое то время работы привыкнешь к этому написанию по началу может быть не привычно, но как напишешь раз 500 - будешь уже на автомате делать)). На самом деле то, что написали выше - там вся информация. Мне приятно, что люди начинают свой путь здесь, успехов. Обнял

Comment: Исправьте ваш ответ, покажите где код с помощью одинарных ковычек.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).